# RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool - ArcPy - ArcGIS Pro - Apply Symbology from Layer

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro

I have this script to apply the symbology from one layer to many. But when I try and run it, I get the following error: `RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool`

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import arcpy  

# Reference current project and mapframe.  
relpath = r'C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python'
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(relpath + r'\CenterHeatMaps.aprx')
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]

# Layer file symbology to be imported.  
symbology_layer = (r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Annual2017_CA_ReferenceLyrx.lyrx")

# Layer to receive imported symbology.  
layers = m.listLayers("CA201*")  
for lyr in layers:   
    #Maintain the symbology ranges
#   arcpy.update_symbology('MAINTAIN')
    #Apply the symbology
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layers, symbology_layer) 

    #print results
    print(lyr.name)
    count = arcpy.GetMessageCount()
    print (arcpy.GetMessage(count-1))
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get a line number in the error message? Dont combine paths using +, instead use os.path.join. Example: `os.path.join(r'C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python', r'CenterHeatMaps.aprx')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in a **list of layers**: `layers` to the ApplySymbologyFromLayer tool.
instead, you need to pass in just the layer: `lyr`

```
for lyr in layers: 
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, symbology_layer)
```